# Why is my bottom half of android linear layout is shorter than the top half?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Trying this for the last 2 days, but could not figure out why. I have 3 sections in my app. The top button that is about 20% of the total height. The 2nd section and 3rd section should take up the remaining 80% of the height equally, (That is 40% each). I have created the code in xml layout file. I notice that the 3rd section appears to be shorter than the 2nd. What is causing this? I'm attaching my code and screenshot. Some advice would be good. Thanks.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="myapp.shk.com.executivesurvey.fragments.OneFragment">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="40">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code with an empty layout and a layout with an app bar at the top. The UI is properly displayed as you expected. Can you show me the code where you're including this frame layout? So that we can see where the issue is occurring.

Comment: If you're adding that top navigation bar inside this frame layout then calculate the linear layouts' weight accordingly.

Comment: This layout is in a fragment by itself. The tab bar is from the main activity's layout. How do i minus the height of the tab bar? Thanks.